# How to create Azure signalR service as premium

Tags: azure-signalr

I can't see any documentation around creating Premium tier Azure SignalR Service. Has any one managed to deploy one? I don't see any premium options in the portal nor via bicep.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-scale-autoscale

[image]

if the name has only two options, Premium in tier, doesn't make sense, have tried though with no luck
[image]. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's a Github thread where the SignalR developers are active: https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1096  
No answers yet but hoping they see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Premium Tier is now public to all

---

Premium tier has not public released yet. We're preparing for that. It's expected to be public in March.